# Can't connect to database using JDBC (Communications link failure) despite being able to connect by other means

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am running MSSQL on docker using port 1433:

[image]

And am able to connect to it and make queries using a simple tool I downloaded from the internet (SQLDbx):

[image]

However when I try to connect using JDBC by this code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:1433/SocialDB/", "myUsername","myPW");
        
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I wonder if there is some extra step that I have to do when running SQLServer on docker that I am missing, and if not, I wonder what could be causing the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you use jdbc:mysql to connect to MSSQL ?

Comment: You are right. I do not know how I missed this. However, I am receiving another error now:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/SocialDB is not valid.
Did I mistype the connection string in the code?

Comment: Yes, the database (SocialDB?) is perhaps not needed to establish a connection to the server.  Please update your question.

Comment: It worked with this connection string:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SocialDB

Comment: That looks a lot like my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the port number is the default one:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=SocialDB;integratedSecurity=true;"
```

localhost:1433 is the same as localhost